# Configure JBOSS Infinispan for using hibernate level 2 caching

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, infinispan, jboss-eap-7

How to configure JBOSS Infinispan for using hibernate level 2 caching. I am using Spring Boot Application and Spring Data JPA is been used which has been configured to use Hibernate. My application does not  have any kind of xml file.I am new to this caching.So please provide the detail solution for this.

Comment: How do you configure Hibernate ORM, then, without the persistence.xml?

Comment: As i am using Spring data JPA, I have configured hibernate for the implementation of JPA. For that we have to mention the lines in application.properites file
    
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

you can refer to the following link

Comment: you can refer to the following link:

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-jpa-data-hibernate-mysql-maven.html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, add the dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
<artifactId>infinispan-spring4-embedded</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then put this file (infinispan.xml) in your resources folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.2">
    <cache-container default-cache="default">
        <local-cache name="countries" statistics="true">
            <eviction max-entries="200"/>
            <expiration lifespan="600000"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Add to the resources folder the file (application.properties) too:

```
spring.cache.infinispan.config=infinispan.xml
```

Then you add the cache where you want, for example:

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "countries")
public class CountryRepository {

    @Cacheable
    public Country findByCode(String code) {
        System.out.println("---> Loading country with code '" + code + "'");
        return new Country(code);
    }

}
```

Don't forget to enable cache in your Main class:

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

---

There's also a spring boot starter for Infinispan that you can try it if you want.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>inifinispan-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Using the starter you need only set the Spring cache () in your applicationContext.xml.
Create a bean of class SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean.
Then you can annotate the classes you want with @Cacheable.

Examples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is about: you're showing how to use Infinispan in Spring directly, but the question is about Infinispan as 2LC in Hibernate ORM.

Comment: Thanks Elvis, I did the above configuration which you have mention, I was able to cache the data but i am not able to verify its using infinispan only or JBOSS cache and where this cache is stored ? when i logged in to the EAP server admin console i was not able to see "countries" cache inside infinispan, so where this cached is been located? and  how can i verify its using infinispan  or not ? any more configuration are needed ?

Answer (score 1):

1) make sure that `hibernate-infinispan` (with transitive dependencies) is on classpath

2) set

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy = TRANSACTIONAL
javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode = ALL
```

You might also need to set `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` and `hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class` if Spring does not do that for you automatically.

Comment: on class path i have set following properties

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.inifinispan.statistics = true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.infinispan.query.cfg = distributed-    query
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strateg    y = TRANSACTIONAL
    spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode = ALL

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class= jta
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider=infinispan
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager=java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
 at

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.determineCacheKeysFactory(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:483)
 at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:447)
 at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:49)

Comment: I have added the dependence of  hibernate-infinispan, infinispan-spring and infinispan-core in pom.xml file 


@Flavius : Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue ? and due to what reason this issue  is coming. Thanks

Comment: @aeroboy: you use different versions of hibernate-core and hibernate-infinispan. Probably since you've added these dependencies manually, but they're provided by Wildfly/EAP, these are provided as modules and you should only consume them in appropriate versions.